# How to alter the official mongo docker for authentication and data separation?

Tags: mongodb, docker

I want to make two minor improvements on the official MongoDB docker so that it starts with the `--auth` enabled and uses a `separate` data container to store the data. What's the best way to do this?

If all are set, how should I start the shell? Will it be possible for someone without a username and password to access any of the databases available? Which directory should I backup?

**EDIT**

Apparently, this is not enough:

```
docker run --name mymongoname1 -v /my/local/dir:/data/db -d -P mongo:latest
```

Comment: Change the `docker run` parameters of the MongoDB image

Comment: can you see my edit? `docker run` is not enough. it does't support `--auth`. in addition, I don't get how to link the additional docker for the data.

Comment: look at https://github.com/cesanta/docker_auth

Answer (score 0):

OK, so partial answer, because I haven't messed around with docker auth.

Containerising storage is done with a storage container. That's basically a container created off a token instance, with some volumes assigned.

So for elasticsearch (which I know isn't mongo, but it is at least a NoSQL db) I've been using:

```
 docker create -v /es_data:/es_data --name elasticsearch_data es-base /bin/true
```

Then:

```
docker run -d -p 9200:9200 --vols-from elasticsearch_data elasticsearch-2.1.0
```

This connects the container volume to my es container - in this example it passes through a host volume, but you don't actually need to any more, because the container *can* hold the data in the docker filesystem. (And then I think you can push the data container around too, but I've not got that far!)

If you run `ps -a` you will see the data container in `Created` state. Just watch if you're doing a cleanup script that you don't delete it, because unlike running containers, you can freely delete it...

Comment: ok. I think, I got the point. but why I am unable to access the `/es_data` folder? i.e. `drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root`. also, speaking about elastic, how should I backup the data based on the provided solution? finally, would it be advisable to set a username / password provided that I am thinking of using the same setup for both development and production? thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Are you running selinux? Otherwise your container runs as root internally, so you should be fine.

Comment: I am not sure if I get what you mean cause I am newbe with the whole Docker thing, however, my host is on ubuntu 14.04. if this sounds ok, then I still don't get why `root` is fine... if I cannot access it then how can I transfer the data to another location later on?

Comment: Do you have a `/es_data` on your primary host? (I might call it something different in you case though, as it's not elasticsearch) The `-v` means that the path on the left (on the host) should be mounted in the location on the right (in the container). This generally works just fine when I do it, but sometimes `selinux` trips me up.